# Lock next item RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am making a list of modules with a `RecyclerView`, where I enter a module1, open another Activity with its contents, and after pressing the confirm button, I would like it to unlock the next module2. However, I'm not even able to block the next items. I wonder if there is any way to do this? It's like a next mission where I complete phase 1 and release phase 2.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_treinamento);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


    //List of Modules
    this.createModules();

    //ConfigAdapter
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter( listmodule );

    //Config Recycler View
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter );

    //
    //click event
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    recyclerView,
                    new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                            Module module = listmodule.get(position);
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StaticModules.class);
                            i.putExtra("module_text", module.getModule());
                            i.putExtra("info_text", module.getInfo());
                            startActivity(i);



                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                        }
                    }
            )
    );
}



public void createModules() {

    Module module = new Module("Módulo 1", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,");
    this.listmodule.add( module );

    module = new Module("Módulo 2", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,");
    this.listmodule.add( module );

    module = new Module("Módulo 3", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,");
    this.listmodule.add( module );

    module = new Module("Módulo 4", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,");
    this.listmodule.add( module );

    module = new Module("Módulo 5", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,");
    this.listmodule.add( module );

    module = new Module("Módulo 6", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,");
    this.listmodule.add( module );

    module = new Module("Módulo 7", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,");
    this.listmodule.add( module );


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

1. first add a boolean variable locked in Module class like this

> private boolean locked;

initialize it

```
Module module = new Module("Módulo 1", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,",true);
this.listmodule.add( module );
```

2. then in your OnItemClickListener

   ```
   Module module = listmodule.get(position);

   if(module.locked)
   {
       Toast.makeText(activity.this, "Module Locked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   else
   {
       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StaticModules.class);
       i.putExtra("module_text", module.getModule());
       i.putExtra("info_text", module.getInfo());
       startActivity(i);
   }
   ```
3. and on confirm button update module's locked status to false

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you very much!

But, I am not able to change the values ​​"true" and "false", because the button is in another activity.

Comment: implement serializable in your module class.. then get it to another activity using putExtra..and update its value

Comment: Thanks bro, you saved my life !

Comment: Glad to be of help